# Automatic redirect to a mobile friendly site with typo3?

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, typo3, responsive

So ive created a landingpage for my website with quite a few content elements. I did it only using html and pasting to my typo3 backend. I have 2 seperate html codes of that page. One for desktop view, one for mobile view because im not able to make the page responsive.

So now i want that the html code is choosen that fits the correct device type. Is there a typo3 extension or build in way to do this? Maybe a mobile redirect?

First i tried using javascript within both html codes. That did not seem to work.

```
<script>
        function loadAppropriateView() {
            var windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
            if (windowWidth <= 768) {
                // Mobile Ansicht
                document.getElementById("desktop-view").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("mobile-view").style.display = "block";
            } else {
                // Desktop Ansicht
                document.getElementById("desktop-view").style.display = "block";
                document.getElementById("mobile-view").style.display = "none";
            }
        }

        window.addEventListener('resize', loadAppropriateView);
        loadAppropriateView();
    </script>
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not related to TYPO3 at all.

Answer (score 4):

Do I understand this right, you have ONE HTML page, but that single HTML page holds two sections, one for mobile and one for desktop?

If that is the case, CSS media queries are the way to solve this, not javascript, something like:

```
    @media (min-width:768px)  {
      #desktop-view { display: block }
      #mobile-view { display: none }
    }
    @media (max-width:768px)  {
      #desktop-view { display: none }
      #mobile-view { display: block }
    }
```

Note that this is basic implementation; no public TYPO3 extension could solve this. You could only use an extension like bk2k/bootstrap-package to use a theme for your page that is already response.

When TYPO3 generates the output HTML, it cannot know (feasibly) which kind of browser will consume it, so you can't really use i.e. fluid markup to distinguish between it.

The real way to solve this is really implement responsive design into the page. You'll be happier once that's done, this is more worth the effort than working against it.

(Also, redirecting to a mobile site isn't recommended nowadays, because you'd have duplicate content and search engines don't like it.)

Comment: Yes you understand correct.
Im just not able to make true responsive websites.

I tried you media querie way. The desktop version will show up just fine. When i try on mobile device the content element wont show up at all. Empty page. I can not seem to figure out way.

Comment: Ok, it seems to work now. Thanks, great work.
Is that a way that google understands and sees as mobile friendly?

Comment: Great! :)Theres a small chance, but if content is duplicated in both "sections", google will downvote it as "hidden content".

Comment: you can use the aria-hidden attribute to prevent the duplicated content (see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Attributes/aria-hidden)